# Sum Related Collection By Property in Entity Framework (Lazy Loaded)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sum, entity-framework-6

I am in need of some assistance with an Entity Framework query.  I have the following entities:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("InvoiceId")]
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public Guid InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitCost { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to sum the total of all the items where an invoice is Approved.  The problem I'm having is the syntax on getting to the InvoiceDetail level once I filter for the Approved = 1:

```
var myInvoices = context.Invoices.Where(i => i.CreatedById == userId).Include(i => i.CreatedBy).Include(i => i.Details);

var approvedTotal = myInvoices.Where(i => i.Approved == 1).Select([GET TO DETAILS???]);

// my goal is to get the following sum for each detail for all of the approved invoices:
// ((d.Quantity * d.UnitCost) - d.Discount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you wanted to get a sum total of all details after the given calculation had been performed you could do something like this:

```
var approvedTotal = invoices.Where(invoice => invoice.Approved)
            .Select(invoice => invoice.Details.Sum(detail => ((detail.Quantity * detail.UnitCost) - detail.Discount)));
```

So this gives you one total per invoice.

Comment: Is there a way to sum all of them in the single query instead of having to perform a foreach?